# How do you align modular instances so they face outward using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, axis

I am trying to align a number of instanced cubes around the perimeter of a grid, and all the cubes should be rotated so they instance facing outward and upward.

It is not a perfect grid, the intention is that some of the squares can be deleted in the top view to create different shapes.

The cubes are intended to have a blue upward side (Z) and a green outward side.(Y)

The way the perimeter is created is by duplicating the edges and then making a curve.  Then a wall is created that can provide normals for positioning.

As you can see, some of the squares are facing the right direction, but not all of them.

The cubes will eventually be replaced of course.

[image]

This illustrates  it may not be possible with only one cube instance, it may require 'corner cubes' or at least a corner rule.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]
Blender 4.0 file:

[image]

Some examples of other questions that relate to it:

[How to select the outer edges of a plane in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284474/how-to-select-the-outer-edges-of-a-plane-in-geometry-nodes)

[Geometry nodes - Align Instance object to face orientation, rotate normal to longest edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287204/geometry-nodes-align-instance-object-to-face-orientation-rotate-normal-to-lon)

[Geometry Nodes: rotational alignment of objects with reference to other object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277792/geometry-nodes-rotational-alignment-of-objects-with-reference-to-other-object)

[The ways to attach object to other object in certain places](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272607/the-ways-to-attach-object-to-other-object-in-certain-places/272718#272718)

The question that started this:

[How to make instances around the grid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304589/how-to-make-instances-around-the-grid/304607#304607)

Comment: your question is not totally clear to me: how should that two cubes be rotated who are on the diagonal? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSmwo.png

Comment: @Chris, I see your point, there is no way of doing what I intended unless there is a corner piece in the collection with two green sides.

Comment: The best that can be done is if the green and the red sides of the object are always on the outside, even with a corner.  The blank or white sides would always face the inside or bottom of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce a limited success with most of the geo nodes I worked on from this question.

The proviso was that a) the corner squares can have two instances on them.  This means the instances aren't exactly the same size as the grid squares.   b)when editing the base plane, any changes made are extruded edges rather than deletions of squares.

I'd still be open to a better solution.

[image]